# How to run the same class in java with multiple different input files automatically

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea, command-line-arguments

I am wondering how to run a same java class with different command line options without manually change those command line options?

Basically, for inputFile and treeFile, I have more than 100 different combinations of the two files. I can not do "edit configurations" in IntelliJ to get result manually for each combination of treeFile and inputFile.

Could anybody give some suggestions to me such that how to create a loop of those inputFile and treeFile so that I do not need to manually specifying them for each combination.

Your help is highly appreciated!!!!

```
@Option(gloss="File of provided alignment")
public File inputFile;


@Option(gloss="File of the tree topology")
public File treeFile;
```

My java class code is below:

```
public class UniformizationSample implements Runnable
{

@Option(gloss="File of provided alignment")
    public File inputFile;


@Option(gloss="File of the tree topology")
public File treeFile;

@Option(gloss="ESS Experiment Number")
public int rep = 1;

@Option(gloss="Rate Matrix Method")
public RateMtxNames selectedRateMtx = RateMtxNames.POLARITYSIZEGTR;

@Option(gloss = "True rate matrix generating data")
public File rateMtxFile;

@Option(gloss="Use cache or not")
public boolean cached=true;

private final PrintWriter detailWriter = BriefIO.output(Results.getFileInResultFolder("experiment.details.txt"));


public void run()  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    double[][] array;
    EndPointSampler.cached=cached;

    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(rateMtxFile)) {
        array = mapper.readValue(in, double[][].class);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        UnrootedTreeLikelihood<MultiCategorySubstitutionModel<ExpFamMixture>> likelihood1 =
                UnrootedTreeLikelihood
                        .fromFastaFile(inputFile, selectedRateMtx)
                        .withSingleRateMatrix(array)
                        .withExpFamMixture(ExpFamMixture.rateMtxModel(selectedRateMtx))
                        .withTree(treeFile);
        Random rand = new Random(1);
        likelihood1.evolutionaryModel.samplePosteriorPaths(rand, likelihood1.observations, likelihood1.tree);
        logToFile("Total time in seconds: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Mains.instrumentedRun(args, new UniformizationSample());
}


public void logToFile(String someline) {
    this.detailWriter.println(someline);
    this.detailWriter.flush();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in IntelliJ IDEA. However, you can modify your `UniformizationSample` class so that it will take the input data as method parameters, and write another Java class that will loop through your inputs and call your class with the necessary parameters.